# Custom select table field in system.xml not showing selected option

Tags: magento2

I've created a module with a custom config table. One of the columns is a select box with few options. When I select option and save configuration, selected option is saved in a DB table but not showing in admin.

My setup is like this:

system.xml

```
<field id="document_name_map" translate="label comment" sortOrder="21" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Document Name Mapping</label>
                <frontend_model>Custommodule\Name\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\DocumentNameMapping</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
```

DocumentNameMapping.php

```
protected function _prepareToRender() {
    $this->addColumn('document_name', ['label' => __('Document Name'), 'type' => 'store']);
    $this->addColumn(
        'component_code',
        [
            'label' => __('Primgroup Document Component Code'),
            'renderer' => $this->_getComponentCodeRenderer()
        ]
    );
    $this->_addAfter = false;
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
 */
protected function  _getComponentCodeRenderer()
{
    if (!$this->_typeRenderer) {
        $this->_typeRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            '\Primegroup\Oneflow\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Type\ComponentCode',
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]

        );
    }
    return $this->_typeRenderer;
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $componentCode = $row->getData('component_code');
    $options = [];
    if ($componentCode) {
        $key = 'option_' . $this->_getComponentCodeRenderer()->calcOptionHash($componentCode);
        $options[$key] = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
}
```

and ComponentCode.php is creating options from product attribute.

So all this creates this table:
[image]

So, when I choose option and save I can see that right selected option is saved in a DB but here always showing just first.

In DB:`a:1:{s:18:"_1498484025538_538";a:2:{s:13:"document_name";s:5:"jhgjg";s:14:"component_code";s:3:"INN";}}`

I noticed that selected field looks like:

```
<select name="groups[rendering_settings][fields][document_name_map][value][_1498462459122_122][component_code]" id="" class="" title=""><option value="TAG">TAG</option><option value="WRAP">WRAP</option><option value="WRP">WRP</option><option value="INN">INN</option><option value="CVR">CVR</option><option value="ITM">ITM</option></select>
```

I really think that some JS needs to be changed, because in that select box code I cannot see `option_`

**EDIT [SOLVED]**

So if your config table contains input fields only, you can use this as a 
`<backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>`

But If your config table contains fields like dropdowns, multiselect...you will need to make a custom backend_module that will do serialisation of a data. In my case I've created this:
`<backend_model>Custommodule\Name\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\DocumentNameMapping</backend_model>`
that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Custommodule\Name\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class DocumentNameMapping extends Value
{
    /**
     * @var Random
     */
    protected $mathRandom;

    /**
     * DocumentNameMapping constructor.
     *
     * @param Context               $context
     * @param Registry              $registry
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface  $config
     * @param TypeListInterface     $cacheTypeList
     * @param Random                $mathRandom
     * @param AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param AbstractDb|null       $resourceCollection
     * @param array                 $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        Random $mathRandom,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $result = [];
        foreach ($value as $data) {
            if (empty($data['document_name']) || empty($data['component_code'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $documentName = $data['document_name'];
            if (array_key_exists($documentName, $result)) {
                $result[$documentName] = $this->appendUniqueCompCodes($result[$documentName], $data['component_code']);
            } else {
                $result[$documentName] = $data['component_code'];
            }
        }
        $this->setValue(serialize($result));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Process data after load
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterLoad()
    {
        $value = unserialize($this->getValue());
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = $this->encodeArrayFieldValue($value);
            $this->setValue($value);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Encode value to be used in \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
     *
     * @param array $value
     * @return array
     */
    protected function encodeArrayFieldValue(array $value)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($value as $documentName => $componentCode) {
            $id = $this->mathRandom->getUniqueHash('_');
            $result[$id] = ['document_name' => $documentName, 'component_code' => $componentCode];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Append unique countries to list of exists and reindex keys
     *
     * @param array $docNamesList
     * @param array $compCodesList
     * @return array
     */
    private function appendUniqueCompCodes(array $docNamesList, array $compCodesList)
    {
        $result = array_merge($docNamesList, $compCodesList);
        return array_values(array_unique($result));
    }
```

}

Example suggested by Aaron was perfect for solving this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Any help for saving dropdown and 3 input field?

Comment: can you open this codes on github or elsewhere? I'm facing similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like this, it's a good idea to try and find an example in the magento core code of what you're trying to do. In this case, the `countrycreditcard` field in the `Magento\Braintree` module will do. This is the field declaration:

```
<field id="countrycreditcard" translate="label" sortOrder="220" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Country Specific Credit Card Types</label>
    <frontend_model>Magento\Braintree\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\CountryCreditCard</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Braintree\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\CountryCreditCard</backend_model>
    <config_path>payment/braintree/countrycreditcard</config_path>
</field>
```

The main point where your code deviates from the example is the `backend_model` being used. You should look at `Magento\Braintree\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\CountryCreditCard` and adapt it to your specific field to create a custom backend model to use (instead of `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized`). It should be mostly a matter of replacing 'country_id' and 'cc_types' with your own column ids.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron, that was exactly what I was looking for.
I've Edit my question based on your answer.